# How to fix this links diplacement in VimFx plugin?

Tags: firefox, vim

Links do not appear where they should. It happens when I zoom in on the page.

**100% scale**
[image]

**130% scale**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

decision
The quick fix: Disable “Zoom text only”. (Uncheck View > Zoom > Zoom text only).
https://github.com/akhodakivskiy/VimFx/issues/554